# VBA code does not jump to cell

Tags: vba, excel

Hy I am trying to make a code that jumps to a cell.

The address is stored in a variable.

I tried 2 options, but both do not work with the variable.

They work fine with the concrete cell address.

```
Dim stMsg As String
Dim x As String

 x = Left(stMsg, Len(stMsg) / 2) 'x = 'Sheet2'!$C$8

    '1 Option
    Application.Goto Reference:="x" 'this works with format: Sheet2!R8C3

    '2 Option
    With Range("x")  'this works with format: 'Sheet2'!$C$8 , which is exactly x
    .Parent.Activate
    .Activate
    End With
```

It gives me

> Method 'Range' or object'_Global' failed" error.

`stMsg` is a variable found in the first part of the macro. The first part take a formula in a cell and find the precedents in the formula, which are 2. `stMsg` stores them both, that's why I split it with x. The value of `stMsg` is 'Sheet2'!$C$8'Sheet2'!$C$8

How can I make it work with x?

Comment: you say you have two options working: why don't you use them?

Comment: they do not work with the variable

Comment: @tombata : it's because it's not a variable, check my answer! ;)

Comment: WHY are you trying to do this?  There may be a better way.  What is the value of `stMsg` and how was that variable created?

Comment: It seems really strange to be taking the length of a string, dividing that length by 2 (rounding any 1/2s to the nearest even number - e.g. if `stMsg` is 11, 12 or 13 characters long you would calculate 6, if it was 14 characters long you would calculate 7, if it was 15, 16 or 17 characters long you would calculate 8, etc), and then expecting that many characters taken from the start of the string to be a valid range address.

Comment: You say you have `stMsg='Sheet2'!$C$8'Sheet2'!$C$8` thus `x='Sheet2'!$C$8'` and that `2 option` works with such an `x`: what's the problem then?

Comment: @YowE3K  the string is always an even number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x`is your variable and you are trying to use it as `"x"`, which is a text only containing the letter **x**

So your code should be more like this :

```
Dim x As String
x = Left(stMsg, Len(stMsg) / 2)

'''Option 1
Application.Goto Reference:=x

'''Option 2
With Range(x)
    .Parent.Activate
    .Activate
End With
```

And working for both options with : 
Input provided by OP : `'Sheet2'!$C$8'Sheet2'!$C$8`

```
Sub test_tombata(stMsg As String)

Dim x As String
x = Left(stMsg, Len(stMsg) / 2) 'x = "'Sheet2'!$C$8"
'Debug.Print x

'''Option 1
Application.Goto Reference:=Sheets(Replace(Split(x, "!")(0), "'", vbNullString)).Range(Split(x, "!")(1))

'''Option 2
With Range(x)
    .Parent.Activate
    .Activate
End With

End Sub
```

And working for both options with : 
Input provided by OP : `'Sheet2'!$C$8`

```
Sub test_tombata2(x As String)

'''Option 1
Application.Goto Reference:=Sheets(Replace(Split(x, "!")(0), "'", vbNullString)).Range(Split(x, "!")(1))

'''Option 2
With Range(x)
    .Parent.Activate
    .Activate
End With

End Sub
```

Code to try both :

```
Sub TEST_test_tombata()

test_tombata "'Sheet2'!$C$8'Sheet2'!$C$8"

test_tombata2 "'Sheet2'!$C$8"

End Sub
```

Comment: @tombata : What is your input in for `stMsg`?

Comment: `stMsg` comes from the first part of the macro. It is the precedents of a formula in a cell. So `stMsg` finds the precedents in a formula (there are 2 precedents) and then I want to go to the first precedent. I use x to split them, which works fine, but the jump to the cell does not.

Comment: @tombata : So what are the **values** for `stMsg`? Use `Debug.Print stMsg` and tell me what it is.

Comment: the value of `stMsg` is 'Sheet2'!$C$8'Sheet2'!$C$8

Comment: @tombata : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff839232.aspx See that and fully working code

Comment: @tombata : This is working so please take time to accept an answer and close that question

Comment: It is stil not working with me. If I write it this way `With Range("'Sheet2'!$C$8")` it works. However, it does not work with `x`   `With Range(x)` and  `x='Sheet2'!$C$8 `

Comment: @tombata : It should be `x ="'Sheet2'!$C$8"` and it is working with that. Also, you don't need both for what you are trying to do, so why bother?

Comment: I need it to work with x. Both `With Range(x)` and `With Range("x")` do not work

Comment: @tombata : Man, I'm sorry, but read the 1st line of my answer again and use the code `Sub test_tombata(stMsg As String)` or `Sub test_tombata2(x As String)`. Because those code works

Comment: @tombata : I've added another sub to show that both works : `Sub TEST_test_tombata()`

Answer (score 0):

Hope below is whats you, by assuming K9 is contains the target range:

```
Dim rw, col As integer
rw = Range(Range("K9").Value).Row
col = Range(Range("K9").Value).Column
Application.Goto ActiveSheet.Cells(rw + 0, col - 0)
```

Comment: ? Why Dim `col` as string and fill it with a number?? `rw` is a variant the way you declare it. And you wouldn't have to use `+-0` if you declare the variable with a good fit...

Comment: @R3uK Yeah it should be integer, will edit it, it will work as string though.