# Can access the sheets while macro running until i click menu button

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i still newbie in excel macro vba world, so i need some help with simple coding.

i'm making menu with macro so by clicking it would go to the sheets and have a back to menu button but the problem is i cannot access the sheets or the cell please help me with the coding.

below are coding i made

```
Private Sub CommandButton15_Click()

Application.Goto Worksheets("14").Range("A1")
Unload Me ' unloads the userform

UserForm3.Show

End Sub
```

and for the UserForm3

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("MENU").Select

UserForm3.Hide

End Sub
```

what coding i need to use so i could access the sheet and the cell while the macro still there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA code does not jump to cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108014/vba-code-does-not-jump-to-cell)

Comment: @R3uK thnx for the link, but that's not answer my question about accessible sheets while macro run

Comment: Your problem isn't clear... What do you mean by *accessible sheets*? Do you have an error? Which message and on which line?

Comment: while macro run i cannot access the sheet, i need to access the sheet to check the data is all  copy completely or not but with my coding i cannot access the sheet. "menu -> sheets -> back to menu"

Comment: What do you mean by access? Get focus to one sheet to see with your eyes if it is there? Check a value on it with some code? Try `UserForm3.Show False` the first time you call it

Comment: UserForm3 is the back to menu button, if false then the back to menu button doesn't appear, i cannot access the sheet while the macro running and must click the back button so the macro get finish to perform. but is that possible to pause macro until i click the menu button? so i can choose the cell and put somemore data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to display your userform in `Modeless` mode with :

```
UserForm3.Show 0
'Or
UserForm3.Show False
'Or
UserForm3.Show vbModeless
```

Comment: wow UserForm1.Show vbModeless is working, good information tnx R3uK. i still newbie need to learn more. LOL.......i can access the sheet but the scrolls not working any solution?

Comment: @MikoIndra : You are welcome! ;) Please accept the answer as it solved your issue! ;)

Comment: :i can access the sheet but the scrolls not working any solution?

Comment: @MikoIndra Did you use `Application.ScreenUpdating` in your code? Can you move the sheet using arrow keys?

Comment: I hate it when suddenly the answer is so easy in front of my eyes.......your are correct @R3uK i need to use vbmodeless and also put it at the right userform, and now all goodd.........facing the problem made me learn a lot tnx for the help

Comment: @MikoIndra : I know the feeling! ;) But don't worry, it'll become less and less frequent! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pick one of your worksheets to use as a reference; let us say worksheet name = "XXX".
Pick a cell in "XXX", let us say cell "B2".
Add below code to your macro at the point you want to enable the user to access the worksheets/cells so that the user can type or do whatever he/she needs to do.
Once the user is done with his/her work, he/she will go to worksheet "XXX", and type the word "END" in cell "B2" to allow the macro to resume running.

```
Do While Worksheets("XXX").Range("B2") <> "END"
    t1 = Now

    While Now < t1 + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        DoEvents
    Wend

    If UCase(Worksheets("XXX").Range("B2")) = "END" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Wow.....this new to me, i will made new workbook so i could try your suggestion @Ping Pang Poo icu tnx......i'll update soon for the results